# Spring @Value annotation not working

Tags: java, spring

Properties annotated with @Value are not being set on my beans.

My context and classes are inside a jar that is on the classpath of another project. Its spring context imports my spring context and my spring context loads a config file from the classpath and contains various bean definitions.

Lazy loading is not being used anywhere, my jar is using Spring 3.1.4 and the project using my jar is using Spring 3.2.3.

Logger showing properties file is loaded when the external project loads it's context (which imports mine)

```
[main] INFO  Loading properties file from class path resource [connector-config.properties] - (PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172:)
```

Excerpt from my Spring context:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:connector-config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
    <!-- The actual beans referenced are not foo bar and com but should not be relevant to this issue -->
<bean id="requestGenerator" class="com.connector.RequestGenerator">
    <constructor-arg name="foo" ref="foo" />
    <constructor-arg name="bar" ref="bar" />
    <constructor-arg name="com" ref="com" />
</bean>
```

config file that is on classpath of project using my jar

```
ruleType=PAUL
response.poolSize=10
ack.poolSize=10
#This needs to be in minutes
max.run.time=100
base.dir=\\
```

Class from external project loading a bean from my context:
**By inspecting the requestGen object in Eclipse debug mode I can see the property ruleType is null.** Given the above properties file, ruleType should be "PAUL" but it is null.

```
public class App
{
public static void main(Straing[] args)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-context.xml");
    RequestGenerator requestGen = context.getBean("requestGenerator", RequestGenerator.class);
```

Comment: will you post RequestGenerator ? what value you are expecting set

Comment: Posted the relevant part of RequestGenerator and the properties file

Comment: Show us the rest of the bean configuration, specifically the `requestGenerator` bean definition.

Comment: Nothing you've shown seems to indicate the behavior you've described. Show us where you see that the field `ruleType` is `null`. Do you get an NPE? Show us the stack trace?

Comment: My bad, let me fix up my post. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Also, do you have `<context:annotation-config />` or `<context:component-scan />`  in your config?

Comment: Fixed up my post showing all relevant parts. I didn't include all the beans in my context, there are about 20. There is no componet-scan (I don't have any @Component annotated classes, I don't have annotation config, forgot all about it. Will add it and retest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `@Value` annotation is processed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is typically registered if you have a `<component-scan>` or `<annotation-config>` configuration in XML (or directly with a bean definition). You need to add either of those, probably `<annotation-config>` since you've said you don't have any `@Component` classes.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was a missing <annotation-config>. Couldn't see the forest from the trees.

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring 3.1 it isn't recommended to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for such task. For more info see its [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

From other side, show, please, your `connector-config.properties` and the code of `RequestGenerator` to have more info about an issue.

Comment: This solution actually worked for me, not the accepted answer. In my case I had some older Spring configurations that defined PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Once I removed those references, everything worked as documented.