# How to add parameters to JUnit tests? Is it possible to add them like in testNg?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, junit, testng

I would like to know, if it is possible to add parameters to Junit tests like you do it in testNg with the xml-Files. I know that you can have parameterized tests in Junit, but that's not what I want.

A short example how I do it now:

```
String example = "test"
String name = "test
...
@Test
public void testCase(){
    Page.addParameter(example);
```

And I want to get rid of these variables in the method, and want to get it from a xml-File or an other method.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spring you can annotate JUnit test with `@ContextConfiguration` passing some `context.xml` configuration, where you can also specify String properties.

For this you have to add dependency on String Test (org.springframework:spring-test) and use it similar to this example (in Groovy):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ['/config/dao-context.xml'])
class ClientServiceImplTest {
    ...
}
```

UPDATE:

You can add following bean to your context.xml, to load properties from some .properties file

```
// context.xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
  <property name="location" value="file:test\resources\config\server.properties"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />


// Java code using property - autowired value by Spring
@Value("${server.dataPassword}")
private String dataPassword;

// server.properties
server.dataPassword=pwd
```

Comment: How to get the values out of the xml-File or communicate with them?

Comment: @Buzz: I updated my answer to show how to load properties with Spring and use them in Java code

Comment: Obviously I'm doing something wrong. If I want to access the variables like you mentioned it, I always get null as value for the variable.

Comment: @Buzz: this is probably because you don't set component-scan for autowiring. I updated context.xml to show how it could be done (I use Spring 4). In any case you can easily find documentation by googling "spring value annotation"

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672263/spring-value-annotation-not-working)

Comment: is there any chance to load more than one class for the testcase, to get different input values for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do it using this 3rd party project called  [junit-dataprovider](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider/wiki/Features)  on GitHub.  You could basically return a `Map<String,String>` object from the data-provider that has a single row of columns from a spreadsheet, passing it in as a single argument to your test method, and then you have access to all of those values as parameters.   You could also pass in a "Page" object (or a Selenium helper object/driver) as an argument as well if you generated that within your data-provider.