# Pass parameters to JUnit test from the TestSuite class

Tags: java, junit

I want to create 2 JUnit TestSuites. They both utilize the same test classes, but they should each use different parameters. For example, in test suite A, I want my data to be collected from file A and to be written to database A. In test suite B, I want my data to be collected from file B and to be written to databaseB.

The reason I use testSuites for this is because:

1. I can put all the specific parameters in the testsuite classes
2. I can reuse the testclasses
3. I can choose which testsuite to run. I do not want all tests to always run with all possible paramaters!

The problem is I cannot really pass the parameters. I understand the way the Parameterized class works with JUnit, but it does not allow point 3 in the list above. If I use the code below it will run my test class with both databse connections, which is not what I want to achieve.

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class TestCheckData
{
    private File file;
    private DatabaseSource databaseSource;

    public TestCheckData(File file, DatabaseSource databaseSource)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.databaseSource = databaseSource;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data1()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]
        {
            { TestSuiteA.DATA_FILE_A, TestSuite1.DATABASE_A }, 
            { TestSuiteB.DATA_FILE_B, TestSuite1.DATABASE_B }
        });


    }
```

I already find some way of passing configurations in a spring context [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506618/how-to-add-parameters-to-junit-tests-is-it-possible-to-add-them-like-in-testng), but I'm not using any special framework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this would be a little unconventional, but you could add a different Test class to the beginning of each suite run that would set the parameters you want to use for that test.  So you'd have classes like:

```
public abstract class StaticParameters {
  public static File dataFileToUse = null;
  public static DatabaseSource databaseToUse = null;
}

public class Suite1Params extends StaticParameters {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setParams() {
    dataFileToUse = DATA_FILE_A;
    databaseToUse = DATABASE_A;
  }
}

public class Suite2Params extends StaticParameters {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setParams() {
    dataFileToUse = DATA_FILE_B;
    databaseToUse = DATABASE_B;
  }
}
```

Then you'd just make `Suite1Params` or `Suite2Params` the first in your suite list.  You might have to add a fake `@Test` entry to the params classes, I'm not sure if the `Suite` runner requires that.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the tests so that they get the parameters from a config file.  This way you would always only have 1 Suite.

The path of the config file can be looked up via a System property.

Then on the invocation of the test suite, you could pass in a different config file by changing the property using the -D option on the JVM.

So for example if you named the proprerty `env.properties` then your command would be:

```
 %java -Denv.properties=prod.config runMyTests
```

or

```
 %java -Denv.properties=dev.config runMyTests
```

etc

Comment: Do you know how to pass in config files when running the unit tests in Eclipse? I would require two config files, one for suite A and for suite B, but how can I tell me testrunner to use A or B?

Comment: @user1884155 yes.  If you go to Run Configurations... Then edit the configuration.  The JRE tab has a text area for entering VM arguments.  That is where you would put the `-D` options you want to add (including the "-D" )